# Show multiple pages of PDF with Angular and pdf.js

Tags: angularjs, pdf.js

I want to show PDFs in my angular application. It should be possible to show multiple pages at once and to search inside the PDF.
I tried [angularjs-pdf](https://github.com/sayanee/angularjs-pdf) to do so, but it lacks these features. Is there a angular wrapper for [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) that can do this? Or can somebody get me startet on how to implement pdf.js in my angular application without a wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this statement:

> "*I want to show PDFs in my angular application*"

Anyone searching for this, could ought to check out ng2-pdf-viewer, for more information on this module, can check this out [ng2-pdf-viewer PdfShowcase](https://pdfviewer.net/ng2-pdf-viewer/getting-started)

Basically, this module could somewhat allow one to display more than one PDF in a single screen.

1. app.component.ts

   ```
   // Declare the pdf as an empty array
   pdfs = [];

   // Assuming requesting PDFs from server through MVC style
   getPdfs(){
     this.getPdfService.getPdfs().subscribe(response => {
       response.body.forEach((value, index) => {
         this.pdfs.push({
           id: index,
           obj: window.URL.createObjectURL(value);
         });
       });     
     });
   }
   ```
2. app.component.html

   ```
   <div *ngFor="let pdf of pdfs, index as i;">
     <div *ngIf="pdf[i]">
       <pdf-viewer
        [rotation]="0"
        [original-size]="true"
        [show-all]="true"
        [fit-to-page]="true"
        [zoom]="0"
        [zoom-scale]="'page-width'"
        [stick-to-page]="true"
        [render-text]="false"
        [external-link-target]="'blank'"
        [autoresize]="true"
        [show-borders]="true"
        [src]="pdf.obj"
        (after-load-complete)="onPdfComplete($event)"
        (error)="onPdfError($event)"
        style="width: 100%; height: 800px;">
       </pdf-viewer>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```

If this library is not suitable for your use case, you may try with other libraries which uses iframe or similar strategy.  Refer here is a [useful source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56859057/accessing-multiple-pdfs-with-ngx-extended-pdf-viewer) worth checking it out.

I know I'm a little bit late for this post but thought of posting here might help some folks who is looking for the same thing.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

***From ng2-pdf viewer page, it recommends*** your desire "angular wrapper for pdf.js", There are a ton of built in functionality Mozilla's viewer supports; such as print, download, bookmark, fullscreen, open file, zoom, ***search,***......

> If you need to display multiple PDF files simultaneously and if you don't mind using iFrames, I recommend ng2-pdfjs-viewer. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdfjs-viewer